# Update targets in classification images

Tags: pytorch

Why are we updating targets in the implementation of bayesian cnn with mc dropout here?

https://github.com/sungyubkim/MCDO/blob/master/Bayesian_CNN_with_MCDO.ipynb?fbclid=IwAR18IMLcdUUp90TRoYodsJS7GW1smk-KGYovNpojn8LtRhDQckFI_gnpOYc

```
def update_target(target, original, update_rate):
        for target_param, param in zip(target.parameters(), original.parameters()):
            target_param.data.copy_((1.0 - update_rate) * target_param.data + update_rate*param.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The implementation you have referred to is a data parallel one.

Which means, the author intends to train multiple networks with the same architecture but different hyper-parameters.

Although in an unconventional way, this is what `update_target` does:

```
update_target(net_test, net, 0.001)
```

It updates the net_test with a lower learning rate compared to net, but with the exact same parameter changes applied to original net, that is actually being trained. Only the change scales is different.

I am assuming that this is found to be useful in terms of computational efficiency, since only one of the networks are actually being "trained" during main training phase:

```
outputs = net(inputs)
loss = CE(outputs, labels)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

One less forward pass and one less backprop per step.

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: I’m a little stuck because I’m a beginner in pytorch, could you please tell me what does this part exactly is it a comparison or what ?
def main():
for lenet in lenets:

            ...............
save(lenet.__name__, net, net_test)

Comment: My pleasure. Please consider accepting my answer if you think it clarifies the purpose of the function that you have posted.

Comment: Perhaps you could send this as another question. The part that you are referring to is the main loop. It trains three different networks. Then tests them and then saves the final state of the networks. The main loop prints the performances of all three networks so yes, you could consider it as a comparison of them. The three networks by the way are included as global variables: `lenets = [Net, Net_DO, Net_MCDO]`